# ArcGIS JS 4.0 API map tiles do not load when foundation.css is added

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, arcgis-js-api

I'm trying to use zurb foundation with ArcGIS javascript API 4.0. Without adding foundation.css, the map works perfectly but when I add the foundation.css file the base map or map tiles don't load so its just a white screen, everything else works like the graphics and zoom controls all work. Am I missing something?

my index.html file:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/css/main.css">

//This line causes problem
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../lib/foundation/css/foundation.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle or add foundation.css file here... So that we can produce the same issue....

Answer (score 0):

from the description of your problem, foundation.css have overwritten some esri css. CSS include ordering matters, so if you include foundation.css first then include esri's main.css after it then it should probably work (but something in foundation.css might break).

If you have the time, try comparing both css and find out which part of their definition clash and fix it manually